# I need to capture the filename and file path of where

Tags: excel, vba, export, ms-project

I need to capture the filename and file path of where Project exports to Excel,

I use the code;

```
FileSaveAs FormatID:="MSProject.ACE", Map:="Map 1"
```

but can't work out how to capture where the user has exported the file to (the excel version)

Thanks

Ronan

Comment: I haven't used MSProject, but for other MS products, the "FullName" property gives the path as well.  Try Application.ActiveProject.FullName.

Comment: The line activeProjectName = Application.ActiveProject.Name gives me the Project name and it's path, but I need to capture where a user saves the Excel output, so I can reopen it later.

Thanks

Ronan

Answer (score 1):

Try to use your own dialog box and then save the file:

```
Dim SavePath As Variant
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    .Title = "Please select location to save file"
    If .Show = True Then
        SavePath = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        SavePath = False
    End If
End With

FileSaveAs Name:= SavePath, FormatID:="MSProject.ACE", Map:="Map 1"
```

Comment: This is the way to do it as there's no way to know where the user saved it themselves.